# Java Socket Programming MultiPlayer Kart Racing Game

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Basically, I am developing a multiplayer kart racing game in Java using TCP as the transport protocol.
Below are my codes, may I know why the gameframe is not showing up after the IP Address has been typed? Instead, currently it will only be shown after the server has closed down. I am using multi-threading to support sending and receiving.

```
Main (Client):-

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String ipAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the address: ");
        if (!ipAddress.isEmpty())
        {
            // Main program to declare GameFrame object
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 8888);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            Thread thread = new Thread(new GameFrame(socket, reader, writer));
            thread.start();
        }
    }

GameFrame:-

public class GameFrame extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    // Exit message
    private final String message = "Are you sure you want to exit the game?";
    
    // Exit message popup title
    private final String title = "Exiting Game";
    
    // Declare RacingTrack object
    private RacingTrack racingTrack;
    
    // Declare JFrame object
    private JFrame mainGameFrame;
        
    public GameFrame(Socket socket, BufferedReader reader, DataOutputStream writer)
    {
        racingTrack = new RacingTrack(socket, reader, writer);
        
        mainGameFrame = new JFrame();
        mainGameFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 900, 700);
        mainGameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainGameFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainGameFrame.add(racingTrack);
        mainGameFrame.addKeyListener(racingTrack);
        mainGameFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainGameFrame.setTitle("Karts Racing Game");
        mainGameFrame.setFocusable(true);
        mainGameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        
        mainGameFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    mainGameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                    mainGameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("Game Frame Thread running.");
        mainGameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

Server:-
public class Server 
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        int connectedClient = 0;
        
        ServerSocket service = null;
        Socket server = null;

        BufferedReader inputStream;

        DataOutputStream outputStream;

        try
        {
            service = new ServerSocket(8888);
            System.out.println("Server has started.");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }  

        try
        {
            while (connectedClient < 2)
            {
                server = service.accept();
                connectedClient++;
                ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(server, connectedClient);
                System.out.println("Player " + connectedClient + " connected. IP Address: " + server.getInetAddress());
                
                Thread thread = new Thread(clientThread);
                thread.start();
                System.out.println("Player: " + connectedClient + " thread running.");
            }
        }  
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);          
        }
    }
}

ClientThread:-
public class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    Socket socket;
    int playerNum;
    
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    
    int kartNumIndex;
    int x;
    int y;
    int speed;
    
    BufferedReader reader;
    DataOutputStream writer;
    
    ArrayList<ClientThread> clients = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public ClientThread(Socket socket, int player)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.playerNum = player;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            
            writer.writeByte(playerNum);
            writer.flush();
            
            while (keepRunning == true)
            {
                playerNum = reader.read();
                kartNumIndex = reader.read();
                x = reader.read();
                y = reader.read();
                speed = reader.read();
                
                broadcastToAllClients(playerNum, kartNumIndex, x, y, speed);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException iOe)
        {
            iOe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void broadcastToAllClients(int playerNum, int kartNumIndex, int x, int y, int speed)
    {
        try
        {
            for (ClientThread client : clients)
            {
                client.writer.write(playerNum);
                client.writer.write(kartNumIndex);
                client.writer.write(x);
                client.writer.write(y);
                client.writer.write(speed);
                
                client.writer.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException iOe)
        {
            iOe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

RacingTrack Constructor (partial):-
public class RacingTrack extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    Socket clientSocket;
    BufferedReader reader;
    DataOutputStream writer;
    
    int playerNum;
    int kartNum;
    int kartImageIndex;
    int x;
    int y;
    int speed;
    
    private Kart kart1;
    private Kart kart2;
    
    private SoundEffect soundEffect;
    
    private Timer animationTimer;
    
    private final int delay = 0;
    
    private Set<Integer> pressedKeys;
    
    boolean isKart1Lose;
    
    boolean isKart2Lose;
    
    private ElapseCounter kart1T;
    private ElapseCounter kart2T;
    
    /* Coordinates, Width, and Height of the value given and modified */
    /* Racing Track 1 */
    // Grass
    private final int GRASS_X_COOR = 150;
    private final int GRASS_Y_COOR = 200;
    private final int GRASS_WIDTH = 550;
    private final int GRASS_HEIGHT = 320;
    
    // Outer Edge
    private final int OUTER_EDGE_X_COOR = 50;
    private final int OUTER_EDGE_Y_COOR = 100;
    private final int OUTER_EDGE_WIDTH = 750;
    private final int OUTER_EDGE_HEIGHT = 520;
    
    // Inner Edge
    private final int INNER_EDGE_X_COOR = 150;
    private final int INNER_EDGE_Y_COOR = 200;
    private final int INNER_EDGE_WIDTH = 550;
    private final int INNER_EDGE_HEIGHT = 320;
    
    // Mid Lane
    private final int MID_LANE_X_COOR = 100;
    private final int MID_LANE_Y_COOR = 150;
    private final int MID_LANE_WIDTH = 650;
    private final int MID_LANE_HEIGHT = 420;
    
    // Start Line
    private final int START_LINE_X1_COOR = 425;
    private final int START_LINE_Y1_COOR = 520;
    private final int START_LINE_X2_COOR = 425;
    private final int START_LINE_Y2_COOR = 620;
    
    /* Racing Track 2 */
    // Grass
    private final int GRASS_TOP_X_COOR = 450;
    private final int GRASS_TOP_Y_COOR = 240;
    private final int GRASS_LEFT_X_COOR = 260;
    private final int GRASS_LEFT_Y_COOR = 520;
    private final int GRASS_RIGHT_X_COOR = 640;
    private final int GRASS_RIGHT_Y_COOR = 520;
        
    // Outer Lane
    private final int OUTER_LANE_TOP_X_COOR = 450;
    private final int OUTER_LANE_TOP_Y_COOR = 110;
    private final int OUTER_LANE_LEFT_X_COOR = 50;
    private final int OUTER_LANE_LEFT_Y_COOR = 622;
    private final int OUTER_LANE_RIGHT_X_COOR = 850;
    private final int OUTER_LANE_RIGHT_Y_COOR = 622;
    
    // Mid Lane
    private final int MID_LANE_TOP_X_COOR = 450;
    private final int MID_LANE_TOP_Y_COOR = 170;
    private final int MID_LANE_LEFT_X_COOR = 140;
    private final int MID_LANE_LEFT_Y_COOR = 570;
    private final int MID_LANE_RIGHT_X_COOR = 760;
    private final int MID_LANE_RIGHT_Y_COOR = 570;
    
    // Obtain car shape bounds
    private Rectangle kart1Shape;
    private Rectangle kart2Shape;
    
    // Obtain outer edges bound
    private Rectangle outerEdgeLeft = new Rectangle(OUTER_EDGE_X_COOR, OUTER_EDGE_Y_COOR, 1, OUTER_EDGE_HEIGHT);
    private Rectangle outerEdgeTop = new Rectangle(OUTER_EDGE_X_COOR, OUTER_EDGE_Y_COOR, OUTER_EDGE_WIDTH, 1);
    private Rectangle outerEdgeRight = new Rectangle(OUTER_EDGE_X_COOR + OUTER_EDGE_WIDTH, OUTER_EDGE_Y_COOR, 1, OUTER_EDGE_HEIGHT);
    private Rectangle outerEdgeBottom = new Rectangle(OUTER_EDGE_X_COOR, OUTER_EDGE_Y_COOR + OUTER_EDGE_HEIGHT, OUTER_EDGE_WIDTH, 1);
    private Line2D outerEdgeTop2 = new Line2D.Double(OUTER_LANE_TOP_X_COOR, OUTER_LANE_TOP_Y_COOR, OUTER_LANE_LEFT_X_COOR, OUTER_LANE_LEFT_Y_COOR); 
    private Line2D outerEdgeLeft2 = new Line2D.Double(OUTER_LANE_LEFT_X_COOR, OUTER_LANE_LEFT_Y_COOR, OUTER_LANE_RIGHT_X_COOR, OUTER_LANE_RIGHT_Y_COOR);
    private Line2D outerEdgeRight2 = new Line2D.Double(OUTER_LANE_RIGHT_X_COOR, OUTER_LANE_RIGHT_Y_COOR, OUTER_LANE_TOP_X_COOR, OUTER_LANE_TOP_Y_COOR);
    
    private Rectangle innerEdgeLeft = new Rectangle(GRASS_X_COOR, GRASS_Y_COOR, 1, GRASS_HEIGHT);
    private Rectangle innerEdgeTop = new Rectangle(GRASS_X_COOR, GRASS_Y_COOR, GRASS_WIDTH, 1);
    private Rectangle innerEdgeRight = new Rectangle(GRASS_X_COOR + GRASS_WIDTH, GRASS_Y_COOR, 1, GRASS_HEIGHT);
    private Rectangle innerEdgeBottom = new Rectangle(GRASS_X_COOR, GRASS_Y_COOR + GRASS_HEIGHT, GRASS_WIDTH, 1);
    private Line2D innerEdgeTop2 = new Line2D.Double(GRASS_TOP_X_COOR, GRASS_TOP_Y_COOR, GRASS_LEFT_X_COOR, GRASS_LEFT_Y_COOR); 
    private Line2D innerEdgeLeft2 = new Line2D.Double(GRASS_LEFT_X_COOR, GRASS_LEFT_Y_COOR, GRASS_RIGHT_X_COOR, GRASS_RIGHT_Y_COOR);
    private Line2D innerEdgeRight2 = new Line2D.Double(GRASS_RIGHT_X_COOR, GRASS_RIGHT_Y_COOR, GRASS_TOP_X_COOR, GRASS_TOP_Y_COOR);
    
    // Obtain goal line bound
    private Rectangle goalLineBound = new Rectangle(START_LINE_X1_COOR, START_LINE_Y1_COOR, 1, START_LINE_Y2_COOR - START_LINE_Y1_COOR);
        
    // Constructor
    public RacingTrack(Socket socket, BufferedReader reader, DataOutputStream writer)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.writer = writer;
        
        try
        {
            playerNum = reader.read();
            System.out.println("I am Player Number " + playerNum);
        }
        catch (IOException iOe)
        {
            iOe.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // Set this JPanel to allow overlay layout
        // so that the kart icons can be printed above it
        this.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));
        
        // Create kart objects
        // Specify the kart number, x-coordinates and y-coordinates
//        kart1 = new Kart(1, 430, 521);
//        kart2 = new Kart(2, 430, 570);  
        
        if (playerNum == 1)
        {
            kart1 = new Kart(1, 430, 521);

            try
            {
                writer.write(kart1.getKartNum());
                writer.write(kart1.getKartImageIndex());
                writer.write(kart1.getXCoordinate());
                writer.write(kart1.getYCoordinate());
                writer.write(kart1.getSpeed());
                
                writer.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException iOe)
            {
                iOe.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            try
            {
                kartNum = reader.read();
                kartImageIndex = reader.read();
                x = reader.read();
                y = reader.read();
                speed = reader.read();
            }
            catch (IOException iOe)
            {
                iOe.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            kart2 = new Kart(kartNum, x, y);
            kart2.setKartImageIndex(kartImageIndex);
            kart2.setSpeed(speed);
        }
        else if (playerNum == 2)
        {           
            try
            {
                kartNum = reader.read();
                kartImageIndex = reader.read();
                x = reader.read();
                y = reader.read();
                speed = reader.read();
            }
            catch (IOException iOe)
            {
                iOe.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            kart1 = new Kart(kartNum, x, y);
            kart1.setKartImageIndex(kartImageIndex);
            kart1.setSpeed(speed);
            
            kart2 = new Kart(1, 430, 570);

            try
            {
                writer.write(kart2.getKartNum());
                writer.write(kart2.getKartImageIndex());
                writer.write(kart2.getXCoordinate());
                writer.write(kart2.getYCoordinate());
                writer.write(kart2.getSpeed());
                
                writer.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException iOe)
            {
                iOe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        if (playerNum == 1)
            kart1.start();
        else if (playerNum == 2)
            kart2.start();
        
        isKart1Lose = false;
        isKart2Lose = false;

        kart1T = new ElapseCounter();
        kart2T = new ElapseCounter();
                
        pressedKeys = new HashSet<>();
        
        animationTimer = new Timer(delay, new TimeHandler());
        animationTimer.start();      
    }
    
    private class TimeHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {           
            speedLabel.setText("<html>Kart 1 Speed: " + kart1.getSpeed() + " <br> Kart 2 Speed: " + kart2.getSpeed() + "</html>");
                
            kart1Shape = kart1.getKartShape();
            kart2Shape = kart2.getKartShape();

            if (playerNum == 1)
            {
                if (isKart1Lose == false)
                {
                    if (kart1Shape.intersects(outerEdgeLeft))
                        setKart1Lose();
                    else if (kart1Shape.intersects(outerEdgeTop))
                        setKart1Lose();
                    else if (kart1Shape.intersects(outerEdgeRight))
                        setKart1Lose();
                    else if (kart1Shape.intersects(outerEdgeBottom))
                        setKart1Lose();
                    else if (kart1Shape.intersects(innerEdgeLeft))
                        setKart1Lose();
                    else if (kart1Shape.intersects(innerEdgeTop))
                        setKart1Lose();
                    else if (kart1Shape.intersects(innerEdgeRight))
                        setKart1Lose();
                    else if (kart1Shape.intersects(innerEdgeBottom))
                        setKart1Lose();
                    else if (kart1Shape.intersects(goalLineBound))
                        winnerFound(1);
                }
            }
            else if (playerNum == 2)
            {
                if (isKart2Lose == false)
                {
                    if (kart2Shape.intersects(outerEdgeLeft))
                        setKart2Lose();
                    else if (kart2Shape.intersects(outerEdgeTop))
                        setKart2Lose();
                    else if (kart2Shape.intersects(outerEdgeRight))
                        setKart2Lose();
                    else if (kart2Shape.intersects(outerEdgeBottom))
                        setKart2Lose();
                    else if (kart2Shape.intersects(innerEdgeLeft))
                        setKart2Lose();
                    else if (kart2Shape.intersects(innerEdgeTop))
                        setKart2Lose();
                    else if (kart2Shape.intersects(innerEdgeRight))
                        setKart2Lose();
                    else if (kart2Shape.intersects(innerEdgeBottom))
                        setKart2Lose();
                    else if (kart2Shape.intersects(goalLineBound))
                        winnerFound(2);
                }
            }
            
            if (kart1Shape.intersects(kart2Shape))
            {
                if (playerNum == 1)
                    isKart1Lose = true;
                else
                    isKart2Lose = true;

                if (playerNum == 1)
                    kart1T.setStop();
                else
                    kart2T.setStop();

                animationTimer.stop();

                if (playerNum == 1)
                    kart1.stop();
                else
                    kart2.stop();
            } 

            if (isKart1Lose == true && isKart2Lose == true)
                bothKartsCrashed();
            
            repaint();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);       
        
        super.setBackground(Color.gray);

        Color c1 = Color.green;
        Color c2 = Color.black;
        Color c3 = Color.white;

        g.setColor( c1 );
        // x-coordinate, y-coordinate, width, height
        g.fillRect( GRASS_X_COOR, GRASS_Y_COOR, GRASS_WIDTH, GRASS_HEIGHT ); // grass

        g.setColor( c2 );
        g.drawRect( OUTER_EDGE_X_COOR, OUTER_EDGE_Y_COOR, OUTER_EDGE_WIDTH, OUTER_EDGE_HEIGHT ); // outer edge
        g.drawRect( INNER_EDGE_X_COOR, INNER_EDGE_Y_COOR, INNER_EDGE_WIDTH, INNER_EDGE_HEIGHT ); // inner edge

        g.setColor( c3 );

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);

        g2d.setStroke(dashed);
        g2d.drawRect( MID_LANE_X_COOR, MID_LANE_Y_COOR, MID_LANE_WIDTH, MID_LANE_HEIGHT ); // mid-lane marker
        g2d.dispose();

        g.drawLine( START_LINE_X1_COOR, START_LINE_Y1_COOR, START_LINE_X2_COOR, START_LINE_Y2_COOR ); // start line
                
        
        if (playerNum == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                writer.write(kart1.getKartNum());
                writer.write(kart1.getKartImageIndex());
                writer.write(kart1.getXCoordinate());
                writer.write(kart1.getYCoordinate());
                writer.write(kart1.getSpeed());
                
                writer.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException iOe)
            {
                iOe.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            kart1.draw(g, this);
            
            try
            {
                kartNum = reader.read();
                kartImageIndex = reader.read();
                x = reader.read();
                y = reader.read();
                speed = reader.read();
                
                kart2.draw(g, this, x, y);
            }
            catch (IOException iOe)
            {
                iOe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (kartNum == 2)
        {
            try
            {
                writer.write(kart2.getKartNum());
                writer.write(kart2.getKartImageIndex());
                writer.write(kart2.getXCoordinate());
                writer.write(kart2.getYCoordinate());
                writer.write(kart2.getSpeed());
                
                writer.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException iOe)
            {
                iOe.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            kart2.draw(g, this);
            
            try
            {
                kartNum = reader.read();
                kartImageIndex = reader.read();
                x = reader.read();
                y = reader.read();
                speed = reader.read();
                
                kart1.draw(g, this, x, y);
            }
            catch (IOException iOe)
            {
                iOe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int speed;
        int carImageIndex;
        
        // Add keypresses
        pressedKeys.add(e.getKeyCode());
        
        for (Iterator<Integer> it = pressedKeys.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
            switch (it.next())
            {
                /* kart blue */
                // Increase speed
                // Each key press increases speed by 10
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    if (isKart1Lose == false)
                    {
                        // get kart's speed
                        speed = kart1.getSpeed();
                        // increase the initial speed by 10
                        kart1.setSpeed(speed + 10);

                        // check if speed is more than 100
                        // if yes, set to 100 (maximum)
                        if (kart1.getSpeed() > 100)
                            kart1.setSpeed(100);

                        // drive the kart forward with the speed
                        moveForwardKart1(kart1.getSpeed());
                    }
                    
                    break;

                // Decrease speed
                // Each key press decreases speed by 10
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    if (isKart1Lose == false)
                    {
                        // get kart's speed
                        speed = kart1.getSpeed();
                        // decrease the initial speed by 10
                        kart1.setSpeed(speed - 10);

                        
                        // check if speed is less than 0
                        // if yes, set to -1, then kart will reverse
                        // minimum is -1
                        if (kart1.getSpeed() < 0)
                        {
                            kart1.setSpeed(-1);
                            moveBackwardKart1();
                        }
                            
                        // check if speed is 0
                        // if no, then drive the kart forward with the set speed
                        if (kart1.getSpeed() > 0)
                            moveForwardKart1(kart1.getSpeed());
                    }
                                        
                    break;
                    
                // Turn the kart to the left
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    if (isKart1Lose == false)
                    {
                        // get kart's image index
                        carImageIndex = kart1.getKartImageIndex();
                        // set the kart's new image index
                        kart1.setKartImageIndex(carImageIndex - 1);

                        // if kart's image index is less than 0
                        // set it to 15
                        if (carImageIndex - 1 < 0)
                            kart1.setKartImageIndex(15);
                    }
                    
                    break;
                    
                // Turn the kart to the right
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    if (isKart1Lose == false)
                    {
                        // get kart's image index
                        carImageIndex = kart1.getKartImageIndex();
                        // set the kart's new image index
                        kart1.setKartImageIndex(carImageIndex + 1);

                        // if kart's image index is more than 15
                        // set it to 0
                        if (carImageIndex + 1 > 15)
                            kart1.setKartImageIndex(0);
                    }
                    
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        pressedKeys.remove(e.getKeyCode());
    }
    
    // For KART1
    // Method that drive the kart forward with appropriate speed
    // speed will affect the pixel displacement
    // (speed / 10) to get the first digit so that the kart can move accordingly
    // if speed is 1, the kart moves by 1 pixel; ie: x + 1 or y + 1 depends on direction
    // if speed is 5, the kart moves by 5 pixel; ie: x + 5 or y + 5 depends on direction
    // this is done by increasing or decreasing the x and/or y coordinates
    private void moveForwardKart1(int speed)
    {
        switch (kart1.getKartImageIndex())
        {
            case 0:
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() - (speed / 10));
                break;

            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() + (speed / 10));
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() - (speed / 10));
                break;

            case 4:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() + (speed / 10));
                break;

            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() + (speed / 10));
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() + (speed / 10));
                break;

            case 8:
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() + (speed / 10));
                break;

            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() - (speed / 10));
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() + (speed / 10));
                break;

            case 12:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() - (speed / 10));
                break;

            case 13:
            case 14:
            case 15:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() - (speed / 10));
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() - (speed / 10));
                break;
        }
    }
   
    
    // For KART1
    // Method that drive the kart backward (reverse)
    // the coordinate(s) will only be increased or decreased by 1 pixel
    // this is done by increasing or decreasing the x and/or y coordinates
    private void moveBackwardKart1()
    {
        switch (kart1.getKartImageIndex())
        {
            case 0:
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() + 1);
                break;

            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() - 1);
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() + 1);
                break;

            case 4:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() - 1);
                break;

            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() - 1);
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() - 1);
                break;

            case 8:
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() - 1);
                break;

            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() + 1);
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() - 1);
                break;

            case 12:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() + 1);
                break;

            case 13:
            case 14:
            case 15:
                kart1.setXCoordinate(kart1.getXCoordinate() + 1);
                kart1.setYCoordinate(kart1.getYCoordinate() + 1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code opens the socket, then raises a new thread to start the game.
The socket, reader and writer are passed into that thread until they arrive at the RacingTrack. The RacingTrack constructor immediately tries to send/receive data, and be aware [reading data is a blocking call](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#read()). It waits until the data has been read.

So unless you close the server and thus the TCP connection is cut, the client still hopes to receive some data and therefore waits patiently.